# Object in sphere(bounding sphere), want it to restrict movement within sphere

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna

i have 2 bounding spheres, one big and one small , the small will be moving inside the big but i dont want it to go outside the big bounding sphere how do i do it?

I tried with the bounding box and the intersection method but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object in sphere(bounding sphere), want it to restrict movement within sphere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737440/object-in-spherebounding-sphere-want-it-to-restrict-movement-within-sphere)

Comment: Please don't re-ask your question.  Amend your original.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some of your code that we can take a look at, so we can determine why it is not working?

Otherwise here is some information on BoundingSpheres:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.boundingsphere_members.aspx

Comment: this was not a question... i was asking this: i have 2 bounding spheres, one big and one small , the small will be moving inside the big but i dont want it to go outside the big bounding sphere how do i do it?